# drupal 7 install erro (An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging information follows)

Tags: drupal-7

**I tried to install drupal 7.10, and when the installation has done 28/29 modules, an error occured:

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging information follows. Path: http://example.com/drupal/install.php?profile=standard&locale=en&id=1&op=do 
>   StatusText: OK ResponseText: ( ! ) **Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds** exceeded in C:\wamp\www\drupal\includes\database\mysql\database.inc on line 153 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0004371192{main}( )..\install.php:0 20.0043834504install_drupal( )..\install.php:26 30.95958976424install_run_tasks( )..\install.core.inc:79 41.929419997120install_run_task( )..\install.core.inc:342 51.930720117440_batch_page( )..\install.core.inc:452 61.931520124560_batch_do( )..\batch.inc:80 71.931520124560_batch_process( )..\batch.inc:161 81.933320214776call_user_func_array ( )..\batch.inc:284 91.933320214800_install_module_batch( )..\batch.inc:284 101.933320215000module_enable( )..\install.core.inc:1538 112.990422114008module_invoke( )..\module.inc:448 122.990422114224call_user_func_array ( )..\module.inc:794 132.990422114360standard_install( )..\module.inc:794 1420.519725138960user_role_grant_permissions( )..\standard.install:400 1529.936125151208MergeQuery->execute( )..\user.module:3030 1629.938825159880DatabaseTransaction->__destruct( )..\user.module:3030 1729.938825159880DatabaseConnection->popTransaction( )..\database.inc:1872 1829.938825159912DatabaseConnection_mysql->popCommittableTransactions( )..\database.inc:1105

Can any one help me to fix it?
Thanks

---

Ok, I fixed it. For people get the same problem: note that the error "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded"

The solution is:
1. go to php.ini file and file the following code snippet

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Resource Limits ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
; http://php.net/max-execution-time
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
max_execution_time = 30
```

2.change `max_execution_time` into 100 or more. Because there are maybe some scripts need more than 30 seconds to execute.

Good luck

Comment: Proper etiquette is to post you solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting the similar kind of error, during drupal installation, with response text "Drupal already installed". I fixed it by making below changes in php.ini,

> max_execution_time = 180
>
> max_input_time = 180
>
> max_input_nesting_level = 300
>
> memory_limit = 512M

Comment: Work like a charm :) 10x!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case: You can not always set max_execution_time via php.ini. For example if you have a shared server, or a free server. In this case, if php ini set does not work, you can set it via .htaccess.

```
php_value max_execution_time 100
```

write line above to your .htaccess file, it will change the php settings well.

You can read more to solve this problem [HERE](http://projecthouse.site88.net/node/5)